# BeautifulSoup Module installed but can't be found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, import, module

I installed beautifulsoup4 on my mac but when I tried to import the module in spyder, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup'

I have tried importing it with:

```
import beautifulsoup4
import beautifulsoup
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
import bs4
```

etc...

I have also tried reinstalling the module in terminal and it says that it is already installed.

I have also checked that it was installed in python 3.9 which is the same version Spyder says it is using on my computer.

I am so confused please help! Where is this module

Update: I think I need a separate environment so I tried to download miniconda but when I try to install it it says that it can't install because I already have it but when I run any conda command in terminal it says command not found so I don't know how to get miniconda

Comment: How, exactly, did you install the module?  What was the command?

Comment: Are you using anaconda? If so, please install the bs4  package in the right env

Comment: I did 'pip3 install beautifulsoup4' to install it

Comment: I also did 'pip install bs4' which also said that it installed successfully but then no module found when I run it

Comment: Yes I am using spyder

Comment: I feel like it is somehow not installed in the right environment but I am new to this and I can't figure out how to change it or why it is not in the right env

Comment: Keep reading up on python virtual environments and how to use them in your IDE. Try to find a tutorial that uses the same type of virtual environment manager you want to work with (conda, venv, virtualenv, pipenv ... sadly there is a confusing many of these so its perfect to make life difficult for starting outers - and the rest of too really). I have also encountered weird issues with environments plus jupyters notebooks where I ended up recreating the environment and the problems went away - not exactly your situation but the point is you just keep at it and that's the life of a coder.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your code. The tutorials I see (there are many online) all import beautifulsoup this way (casing matters - the `B` and the `S` are upper case!):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Example:
https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#making-the-soup

Comment: I tried this and I get no module names 'bs4'